# Ошибка -Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Tags: laravel

Столкнулся с ошибкой:

> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object
>   (View: home/vagrant/projects/Laravel/resources/views/admin/messages/partials/form.blade.php)
>   (View: /home/vagrant/projects/Laravel/resources/views/admin/messages/partials/form.blade.php)

Вот содержимое файла в котором ошибка:   *Laravel/resources/views/admin/messages/partials/form.blade.php*:

```html
<label for="">Заголовок</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок" value="{{$message->title or ""}}" required>

<label for="">Описание</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" value="{{$message->slug or ""}}" required>

<input type="button" class="button" name="" value="Опубликовать">
```

Если убрать `{{$message->title or ""}}`, и заменить допустим на простое абвгд, то все работает, страница загружается.

Вот контроллер *Laravel/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/MessageController.php* :

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.messages.index', [
            'messages' => Message::paginate(16)
        ]);
    }

    
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.messages.create', [
            'message' => [],
            'delimiter' => ''
        ]);
    }

    
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Message::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.message.index'); // ВАЖНО s
    }

    
    public function show(Message $message)
    {
        //
    }

    
    public function edit(Message $message)
    {
        return view('admin.messages.edit', [
            'message' => $message,
            'delimiter' => ''
        ]);
    }

    
    public function update(Request $request, Message $message)
    {
        $message->update($request->except('slug'));

        return redirect()->route('admin.message.index');
    }

    
    public function destroy(Message $message)
    {
        $message->delete();

        return redirect()->route('admin.message.index');
    }
}
```

Модель *Laravel/app/Message.php*:

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'parent_id', 'published', 'created_by', 'modified_by'];

    // Mutators
    public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug(mb_substr($this->title, 0, 40) . "-" . \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('dmyHi'), '-');
    }

}


}
```

Вопрос: как решить эту проблему в моем случае?

Comment: Если убрать `$message->title` но не убрать `$message->slug`, то тоже работает? Не должно работать, в ошибке написано $message не объект. Вы выводите через @foreach из какой переменной? что она содержит?

Comment: Если убрать, то не работает. Я, конечно, мог вас неправильно понять. @foreach у меня один и в нем находится:

`@foreach($messages as $message_list)

    <option value="{{$message_list->id or ""}}">

        @isset($message->id)

            @if($message->parent_id == $message_list->id)
                selected=""
            @endif

            @if($message->id == $message_list->id)
                hidden=""
            @endif

        @endisset

        {!! $delimiter or "" !!}{{$message_list->title or ""}}

    </option>

@endforeach`

Comment: Попробуйте в контрллере написать dd($message). У вас код не работает который через метод index в MessageController?

Comment: Немного не понятно где и в каком виде написать dd($message), если можно по-конкретнее. 
В методе create.

Comment: Я добавил в контроллер `'messages' => null,` но у меня появилась другая ошибка `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...` тогда погуглив мне предложили использовать проверку `@if(!is_null($messages))`, но это вернуло вновь первостепенную ошибку.

Comment: Напишите в метод index следующее: `dd(Message::paginate(16))` Посмотрю что попадает в foreach. Или У вас ошибка в create, а не в index? Напишите `dd(Message::paginate(16))` в метедо который передает сообщения в view

Comment: У меня ошибка в create.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема:  `{{$message->title or ""}}`
Решение:   `{{$message->title ?? ""}}`

Answer (score 0):

Не:

```
$this->title
```

А:

```
$this->attributes['title']
```

=>

```
$this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug(mb_substr($this->attributes['title'], 0, 40) . "-" . \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('dmyHi'), '-');
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Ошибка и не убралась, и не изменилась.